# Lentitud al cargar lista de música en la web

Tags: php, html5, audio

Hola amigos estoy realizando una lista de músicas en formato mp3, lo que pasa es que al abrir el enlace la pestaña tarda demasiado en cargar las músicas(tengo buena conexión a internet). se me hace raro porque e visto sitios web  donde se pueden descargar músicas (donde muestran una lista de músicas) y no tarda demasiado en cargar la pagina.

este es mi codigo:

```
 <body>
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-12"><p class="text-dark font-weight-bold ">MUSICA 1</p></div>
      <div class="col-12"><audio style="width: 500px;" controls><source src="musica/musica1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-12"><p class="text-dark font-weight-bold ">MUSICA 2</p></div>
      <div class="col-12"><audio style="width: 500px;" controls><source src="musica/musica2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-12"><p class="text-dark font-weight-bold ">MUSICA 3</p></div>
      <div class="col-12"><audio style="width: 500px;" controls><source src="musica/musica3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-12"><p class="text-dark font-weight-bold ">MUSICA 4</p></div>
      <div class="col-12"><audio style="width: 500px;" controls><source src="musica/musica4.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-12"><p class="text-dark font-weight-bold ">MUSICA 5</p></div>
      <div class="col-12"><audio style="width: 500px;" controls><source src="musica/musica5.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-12"><p class="text-dark font-weight-bold ">MUSICA 6</p></div>
      <div class="col-12"><audio style="width: 500px;" controls><source src="musica/musica6.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-12"><p class="text-dark font-weight-bold ">MUSICA 7</p></div>
      <div class="col-12"><audio style="width: 500px;" controls><source src="musica/musica7.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio></div>
    </div>
```

he notado que algunas músicas se cargan hasta cierta parte no se si se deberá a eso la lentitud de carga en la pagina, aquí una imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien que pueda ayudarme a optimizar esto, o una manera correcta de hacerlo?
porque demora mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que utilizar el atributo de html5 `preload` con su valor `none` y agregarlo a todos tus etiquetas audio para que de esta forma no realice una carga previa al ejecutarse la pestaña.
Por ejemplo:

```
    <audio style="width: 500px;" controls><source src="musica/musica1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" preload="none"></audio>
```

Evitara que las músicas tengan un precargado en el buffer de audio.

Comment: muchas gracias, la verdad desconocia de ese atributo para las cargas previas

Comment: Es gusto, para servir.